# Python - Animate basemap scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, animation, coordinates, matplotlib-basemap

I have a DataFrame with shape (14403, 438) that consists of longitudes and latitudes as well as values. The DataFrame is as:

[image]

I am plotting the coordinates as:

```
# define map colors
land_color = '#f5f5f3'
water_color = '#cdd2d4'
coastline_color = '#f5f5f3'
border_color = '#bbbbbb'
meridian_color = '#f5f5f3'
marker_fill_color = '#0000ff'
marker_edge_color = 'None'

# create the plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor = '#ffffff', frame_on = False)
ax.set_title('Transportable Array', fontsize = 24, color = '#333333')

#lon_0  center of desired map domain (in degrees).
#lat_0  center of desired map domain (in degrees).
#width  width of desired map domain in projection coordinates (meters).
#height height of desired map domain in projection coordinates (meters).

# draw the basemap and its features
m = Basemap(width = 5500000,height = 3300000,
            resolution = 'l', area_thresh = 1000., projection = 'lcc',\
            lat_1 = 45., lat_2 = 55, lat_0 = 37, lon_0 = -98.)
m.drawmapboundary(color = border_color, fill_color = water_color)
m.drawcoastlines(color = coastline_color)
m.drawcountries(color = border_color)
m.fillcontinents(color = land_color, lake_color = water_color)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 120., 30.), color = meridian_color)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0., 420., 60.), color = meridian_color)

# project the location history points then scatter plot them
x, y = m(stations.loc['longitude'].values, stations.loc['latitude'].values)
m.scatter(x, y, s = 8, color = marker_fill_color, edgecolor = marker_edge_color, alpha = 1, zorder = 3)

# show & save the map
plt.savefig('Transportable_Array.png', dpi = 96, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0.2)
plt.show()
```

I am trying to create an animation that will plot the coordinates for each column and then iterate over the values in the index. In the end I am trying to have it iterate over the 14,403 rows and change the markings color based on the value. I am currently having trouble even animating the plot for the coordinates alone.

I would love to be able to implement bqplot, but the scatter animations I've followed on [GitHub](https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot/blob/master/examples/Advanced%20Plotting/Animations.ipynb) have not worked yet.

The map currently looks like below. It'd be wicked cool if each dot can fluctuate in color based on the current iterations value.

[image]

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **animation** module for this. These are the general steps:

1. Convert the values into a colour
2. Update the color at each step
3. Save the animation

Here is some code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

land_color = '#f5f5f3'
water_color = '#cdd2d4'
coastline_color = '#f5f5f3'
border_color = '#bbbbbb'
meridian_color = '#f5f5f3'
marker_fill_color = '#0000ff'
marker_edge_color = 'None'

# Some dummy data
longVals = np.random.uniform(-120,-80, 1000)
latVals = np.random.uniform(35, 45, 1000)
vals = np.random.uniform(size=(200,1000))

# Be careful - the values that go into the colormap function
#  must be integers between 0 and 254
normalisedVals = 254*(vals-vals.min())/(vals.max()-vals.min())
normalisedVals = normalisedVals.astype(np.int)
cm = plt.cm.spectral_r


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor = '#ffffff', frame_on = False)
ax.set_title('Transportable Array', fontsize = 24, color = '#333333')

# draw the basemap and its features
m = Basemap(width = 5500000,height = 3300000,
            resolution = 'l', area_thresh = 1000., projection = 'lcc',
            lat_1 = 45., lat_2 = 55, lat_0 = 37, lon_0 = -98.)
m.drawmapboundary(color = border_color, fill_color = water_color)
m.drawcoastlines(color = coastline_color)
m.drawcountries(color = border_color)
m.fillcontinents(color = land_color, lake_color = water_color)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 120., 30.), color = meridian_color)
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(0., 420., 60.), color = meridian_color)

x, y = m(longVals, latVals)
scat = m.scatter(x, y, s = 8, c = normalisedVals[0], edgecolor = marker_edge_color, alpha = 1, zorder = 3)


def init():
    return scat,

def animate(i):
    col = cm(normalisedVals[i])
    scat.set_color(col)
    return scat,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=100, interval=20, blit=False, repeat=False)
anim.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=60)
```

I should warn you that for 14k rows this will take a while. 
Also I would recommend saving as an mp4 rather than a gif due to better compression.
If you have any questions let me know!

[image]

Comment: Great work and thanks for commenting, I appreciate it. That is exactly what I am looking for. I am having trouble converting the row values into something I can use as you did. Should I assign the DataFrame row values to an array?

Comment: That's probably what I would do, you could read out all the rows and stack them with numpy. If you have some trouble with this I can give some code to help.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I managed to get it into an array like: `vals = np.array(stations.iloc[2:].values)`, but when it processes I receive: `Invalid RGBA argument: -9223372036854775808`, I am assuming it is trying to create an RGB value based on all the values.

Comment: So I don't think that was the issue. Now it just doesn't save the GIF or mp4. I am following examples on how to do this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: To save the animation as an MP4 just use: anim.save('animation.mp4')

Comment: Make sure you don't have plt.show() anywhere as well

Comment: Absolutely. I need to get my vals within RGB limits, right now the normalizedVals for colors are all one value when I use those codes. I don't think it is getting a min and max value from what I've tried. But, thank you again, you helped me get on track!

Comment: Okay - not sure why that is happening. Try np.max(...) instead of vals.max() maybe?

Comment: `normalisedVals = 254*(n-np.nanmax(vals))/(np.nanmax(vals)- np.nanmin(vals))` seemed to work. But, I'm unable to save any outputs so far. I am using a jupyter notebook currently, and receive this `ValueError: Invalid file object: <_io.BufferedReader name=53>` every time. Looking into it.